# JQuery .click doesn't work like I expect it to. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Why doesn't this function work with jquery-mobile?

When I click in any element it's triggered alert("cell Nº"+60)

```
function insertOnClick(){
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            n = 10 * j + i;
            el = "#num" + n;
            $(el).click(function() {
                alert("cell nº"+n);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not binding 60x the click event to the same element $(el)?

Comment: "dont-work-as-i-want" but what how can we know what you want, we are not mind readers!

Answer (score 6):

as written n will always be the last number you assign that variable - it will be the value at the time the click handler is executed, not the value where you define the function.

### Use a closure

you need to use a closure to achieve what you want:

```
function insertOnClick(){
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            n = 10 * j + i;

            (function(number) {

                el = "#num" + number;
                $(el).click(function() {
                    alert("cell nº"+number);
                });

            }(n));
        }
    }
}
```

### Better Idea

Though, you'd be much better off using a single handler:

```
$('someselector').click(function(e) {
    var number = $(this)[0].id.replace('num', '');
    alert("cell nº" + number);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id^="num"]').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id').slice(3))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, there is no reason to do any looping and there is no reason to add a click event to every element. Give every element a common class and with jQuery 1.7+, use on.

```
$(document).on("click", ".commonClass", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    alert(elem.prop("id"));
});
```

Comment: why not on `el`? also, i think the issue is scope, not global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertOnClick(){
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            n = 10 * j + i;
            el = "#num" + n;
            $(el).click(function(n) {
                return function(){
                alert("cell nº"+n);
                }
            }());
        }
    }
}
```